# Flatten and extract keywords from json field in csv

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to flatten the json,meaning divided all the parameters, so that means I get around 5-6 new columns( as these are all the parameters changing,first set of elements)

so I get output as something as follows:

```
info      paths      endpoints  components
version    modified   added      schemas:added
                                 requestBodies:added
```

I looked into `json_normalize` , `flatten` and `jsonpath`, but somehow neither of these work for the use case. It yields a completely different output to the one I want. It would be really great if someone could help me with this! I seem to be a bit stuck.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the output is supposed to be? I dont understand your explanation. Are those different columns? Is the first row the expected header and the rest values?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear, I hope its understandable now, if not, I will add further clarification

Comment: It's still not clear what values should appear in your output. What would be `version` under `info` in your example? (value associated with `from` or `to` or something else?) Same question for the other fields: should `added` keys be filled with the corresponding values (lists like `['ObjectOfObjects', 'inline_object', 'ObjectOfObjects_inner']` for `schemas:added` in your case..)? `paths:modified` value is a dict: shall it appear in the output as a dict?

Comment: Hi, you label the question as "pandas" but don't actually provide an example data structure in pandas. Please add one to make it clear what the input is and ideally also construct the desired output. Do you want `MultiIndex` in the result? Or not?

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather, it would help if you could create a table with the values you are expecting and not only the headers. You can just use markdown to create a table here for the one row that you provided on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had [for example] a DataFrame `df` with a `diff` column containing nested dictionaries as below:

```py
# import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'diff': [
    {'info': {'version': {'from': '2.0.0_1', 'to': '2.3.4_1'}}, 'paths': {'modified': {'/dummy': {'operations': {'added': ['PUT_1']}}}}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'PUT_1', 'path': '/dummy_1'}]}, 'components': {'schemas': {'added': ['ObjectOfObjects_1', 'inline_object_1', 'ObjectOfObjects_inner_1']}, 'requestBodies': {'added': ['inline_object_1', 'nested_response_1']}}},
    {'info': {'version': {'from': '2.0.0_2', 'to': '2.3.4_2'}}, 'paths': {'modified': {'/dummy': {'operations': {'added': ['PUT_2']}}}}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'PUT_2', 'path': '/dummy_2'}]}, 'components': {'schemas': {'added': ['ObjectOfObjects_2', 'inline_object_2', 'ObjectOfObjects_inner_2']}, 'requestBodies': {'added': ['inline_object_2', 'nested_response_2']}}}
] })
```

[I'm assuming that the dictionaries in `diff` are not stringified; if they are, then they should be parsed with `json.loads`/`ast.literal_eval`/etc.]

---

You could [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) specific nested values to additional columns with something like

```py
def try_get(obj, *keys, defaultVal=None):
    try:
        for k in keys: obj = obj[k]
        return obj
    except: return defaultVal

kSep = '.' ## specify a separator
extractKeys = [ ('info', 'version'), 
                ('paths', 'modified'), 
                ('endpoints', 'added'),
                ('components', 'schemas', 'added'), 
                ('components', 'requestBodies', 'added') ]
for kl in extractKeys:
    df[kSep.join(kl)] = df['diff'].map(lambda d: try_get(d, *kl))
```

[image: op1]

If you wanted the new columns in a new DataFrame instead of adding to `df`:

```py
f_df = pd.DataFrame([{
    # kSep.join(kl): try_get(d, *kl) for kl in df['diff'] ## NO diff COLUMN
    'diff': d, **{kSep.join(kl): try_get(d, *kl) for kl in extractKeys}
} for d in df['diff']])
```

---

Or, if you just wanted to flatten all the nested dictionaries in `diff`:

```py
def flattenDict(obj:dict, kSep='.', kRoot=[], unlistSingles=True):
    if unlistSingles and isinstance(obj, list) and len(obj)==1: return obj[0]
    if isinstance(obj, (list, set, tuple)) and not kRoot:
        return type(obj)(flattenDict(i, kSep, [], unlistSingles) for i in obj)

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        kJoin = lambda kx: kSep.join(kRoot + [kx])
        flatDict = {}
        for k, v in obj.items():
            fv = flattenDict(v, kSep, kRoot+[k], unlistSingles)
            if not isinstance(fv, dict):
                flatDict[kSep.join(kRoot + [k])] = fv
                continue
            for kn, vn in fv.items(): flatDict[kn] = vn
        return flatDict
    
    return obj

# f_df = pd.DataFrame(flattenDict(list(df['diff']))) ## NO diff COLUMN
f_df = pd.DataFrame([{'diff': d, **flattenDict(d)} for d in df['diff']])
```

[image: op2]

Comment: this was quite helpful, thank you so much for your help!